# mySQL right outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

Im quite new to SQL and am trying to construct a query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS s_count FROM solution RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
ON offer.oid = solution.oid ". "WHERE offer.is_solved = 0  ORDER BY offer.creation_time 
DESC LIMIT $interval_begin, $interval_end");
```

The query is supposed to be a liveticker in a shop like environnment: it needs to count all offers that havent been solved and then list them for a certain interval to reflect a certain page of the listing.
eg if there are 25 offers per age, page 2 would be 26-50.

Can anyone spot why the output is 0? All the columns/tables exist and do have test values in them.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the query be like

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS s_count FROM solution RIGHT OUTER JOIN  offer ON offer.oid = solution.oid WHERE offer.is_solved = 0  ORDER BY offer.creation_time  DESC LIMIT".$interval_begin.",".$interval_end);
```

Comment: Rahul: thanks, that was probably part of the problem. However, it still returns 0

Comment: Then we need more details about your database tables.

Comment: Both tables share a medium int called "oid" and there are 3000 test entries in "offer", but 0 in "solution" yet. 
Our aim is to join the number of solutions for each "offer" with the "offer" itself.

Comment: For more testing I would remove the part of the query begining with `ORDER ...` till the end (you don't need them to calculate the number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

looking into your question and your query, I think the most obvious reason(s) why your query always return 0 could be:

1. The table `offer` does not have `is_solved` = 0 for any of its records. As a result, the WHERE condition `offer.is_solved = 0` has no matching entries. Can you please confirm this for your data?
2. The table `offer` has no data and thus the RIGHT JOIN yields no results. But as you have mentioned in one of your comments to Rahul's answer, there are 3000 entries in `offer`, I guess this reason is unlikely.

Aha, there could be another reason too: are you sure the limit and offset, marked by `$interval_begin` and `$interval_end` are correctly set? Perhaps if they are both set to 0, the query will always return 0. Can you try doing an "echo/print" of your query and see how does it exactly look?

Because I have no understanding of your schema, this is only a suggestion, I think that if you have an `offer.is_solved` column, you do not need a RIGHT JOIN with `solution`. The following query should work equally fine, no?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `s_count`
FROM `offer`
WHERE `offer`.`is_solved` = 0
ORDER BY `offer`.`creation_time`
DESC LIMIT $interval_begin, $interval_end;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What for do you need solution table in your query? From your text it looks like

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM offer offer WHERE offer.is_solved = 0  ORDER BY offer.creation_time  DESC LIMIT".$interval_begin.",".$interval_end);
```

would be enough.

"What we need to know is the exact number of solutions for each "offer", not just whether there is any solution at all." - In such case your initial SQL was wrong, it just counted orders. You need something like

```
mysql_query("SELECT offer.oid, COUNT(solution.oid) FROM offer offer LEFT JOIN ON offer.oid = solution.oid WHERE offer.is_solved = 0 GROUP BY offer.oid ORDER BY offer.creation_time  DESC LIMIT".$interval_begin.",".$interval_end);
```